# Parse email subject office 365 flows

Tags: expression, office365, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to get some data parsed out of a subject line in Office 365 Flows. I have an email that has a consistent format:

```
Help Desk [Ticket #12345]
```

I want to get the number '12345' for use in later steps in the flow. So far, I've attempted to use the substring expression in a compose connector:

```
substring(triggerBody()?['Subject'], 20, 5)
```

But I get an error about the string being null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the index being incorrect (to retrieve '12345' from `Help Desk [Ticket #12345]` you need to use `substring(value, 0, 5)` as the index is 0-based), the expression looks correct. But you can take a step-by-step approach to see what is wrong.

To start, take a look at the flow run to see exactly what the trigger outputs are:
[image: E-mail trigger]

If you see the Subject field (as I do in my case), create a variable containing that value only to make sure that you don't have any typo:
[image]

If it works correctly, then you should see in the flow run the subject:
[image: Subject]

If everything is still good at that point, create a new variable with the substring that you want:
[image]

And again, check the value.
[image]

If you got to this point, then you should be able to retrieve the ticket id.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @carlosfigueira tried to extract the subject, but it says "expression is invalid". Can't enter it. Only if I enter `triggerBody()` it works. The result is a string containing the big json object then. What am I doing wrong?